# Extra character appearing while copying a .dat file using c code

Tags: c, file-handling

I am quite new to C and just started the file handling chapter so feel free to correct my code, I insist. In the C code given below , A-Z characters are copied from a dat file called textfile.dat and pasted in another dat file called output.dat

But when i open the output.dat i get a result like this:
A
B
C
D
E
F
G
H
I
J
K
L
M
N
O
P
Q
R
S
T
U
V
W
X
Y
Zÿ <- something weird beside Z ,i have no idea what this is and why is it occurring again and again.Please someone explain this to me
The C code:

```
int main()
{
    char ch;
    FILE *fpin,*fpout;

    fpin=fopen("textfile.dat","r");
    if(fpin==NULL)
        {printf("CANNOT FIND THE DESIGNATED FILE.");
            exit(1);
        }

    fpout=fopen("output.dat","w");

    while(!feof(fpin))
    {
        ch=getc(fpin);
        printf("\t%c",ch);
        putc(ch,fpout);
    }
    fclose(fpin);
    fclose(fpout);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because the `while` loop condition is not what you want as it runs one more time than you wanted:

```
while(!feof(fpin))
```

`feof(fp)` tests whether the `fp` would return a non-zero value only if it's already *one past* the end of the file marker.

I would suggest you use [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgets.3.html) instead to read lines as parse [`sscanf()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/scanf.3.html) as necessary. Reading one character at a time is not very efficient.

```
char buf[1024];

while( fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin) ) {
   ...
   ...
}
```

Remember `fgets()` reads the newline as well if there's space in the buffer. So you may want need remove it if it's a problem. For example, you can do:

```
char *p = strchr(buf, '\n');
if (p) *p = 0;
```

inside the loop (after `fgets()` read the input) to remove the the trailing newline, if any.

Answer (score 1):

`feof(fpin)` tests the EOF indicator; before it gets set, `getc(fpin)` will return the EOF character. What you're seeing in the output is this character. (It's -1, which is 0xFF in a single-byte character.)

Instead, you should do something like:

```
while((ch = getc(fpin)) != EOF)
{
    printf("\t%c",ch)
    putc(ch,fpout);
}
```

This loops until it reads EOF, then breaks out of the loop before the EOF gets printed or written to the output file.

Also: You need to `#include <stdio.h>` and `#include <stdlib.h>` at the beginning of the file.

Comment: Also `ch` should be of type `int` .

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of subtle issue worth noting, but first a little nit, but big enough to talk about. All of your applications have the ability to take arguments on the command line. It is the way you have to pass information to your program in order to prevent hard-coding things like filename, etc. within your code. The standard declaration for `main` is `int main (int argc, char **argv)` (and on Linux you may also see `char **envp`). `argc` will contain the number of arguments on the command line, and `argv[]` will contain a pointer to each of the arguments (`argv[0]` is always the name used to launch the program).

Next, `ch` is type `int`, not `char`. This is the return of `fgetc` and it allows handling of characters containing more than a single byte. Make sure you always use the correct data types.

As you have been pointed to in other answers `while (fpin != feof())` is almost *always* wrong when used in a loop to read a text file. Your choices for reading text from a file is with *character-oriented* input functions like (`getchar`, `fgetc`, etc..) or by reading a line-at-a-time with *line-oriented* input functions like (`fgets` or `getline`), and then there are those limited circumstances where the layout of the data itself makes the `fscanf` set of functions usable. While *line-oriented* input with `fgets` would make your program trivial, it looks like the purpose was to expose you to the *character-oriented* approach.

Taking these considerations into account, you could write your code similar to the following. Note: simple `ternary` operators (e.g. `(test) ? (if true code) : (if false code);` makes it very easy to take the input and output filenames on the command line, while still providing your *default* filenames in the case no arguments are given. This allows the user to specify input/output filenames without being stuck with your hardcoded values. (this also allows reading from a file or `stdin` by default with a simple change)

Give the following a try:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{
    int ch; /* ch is type 'int' */
    FILE *fpin = argc > 1 ? fopen (argv[1], "r") : fopen ("textfile.dat","r");
    FILE *fpout = argc > 2 ? fopen (argv[2], "w") : fopen ("output.dat","w");;

    if (!fpin || !fpout) {
        if (!fpin)  fprintf (stderr, "error: input file open failed\n");
        if (!fpout) fprintf (stderr, "error: output file open failed\n");
        return 1;
    }

    while ((ch = fgetc(fpin)) != EOF) {
        printf ("  %c", ch);
        putc (ch, fpout);
    }
    putchar ('\n');     /* to make stdout output look nice  */
    putc ('\n', fpout); /* POSIX requires newline at EOF    */

    fclose (fpin);
    fclose (fpout);

    return 0;
}
```

**Compile (always enable Warnings)**

You will want to *Always* compile with *Warnings* enabled (`-Wall` at minimum, and `-Wall -Wextra` recommended). The warning will point out to your where your code needs attention. In any code you compile during the time you are learning C, there should be *No* warnings that remain. Example compile string:

```
gcc -Wall -Wextra -O3 -o bin/read_AZ read_AZ.c
```

**Input File**

```
$cat dat/AZ.txt
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

**Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/read_AZ dat/AZ.txt dat/AZout.dat
  A  B  C  D  E  F  G  H  I  J  K  L  M  N  O  P  Q  R  S  T  U  V  W  X  Y  Z
```

**Output File**

```
$cat dat/AZout.dat
ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ
```

**note:** no funny characters at the end... Let me know if you have any questions.